# LINQ Query Field<T> with dynamic type

Tags: c#, linq

I need to perform a sum function on a datatable with linq

```
 var query = from row in data.AsEnumerable()
             group row by row.Field<string>("ID") into grp
             select new
             {
                 Id = grp.Key,
                 sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("AMOUNT"))
             };
```

The problem is that the field AMOUNT is not always decimal but sometimes it may be Int64 or Int32. So when the field is Int32, i get an exception that cast is not valid

Is there a way to have a dynamic field type in the sum function?

Comment: Be careful once you put `.AsEnumerable()` you are no longer in the database you are in memory

Comment: Are you using EF ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Not strictly true, but it means any action you make against it (i.e. `.Where(...)` or `.Single(...)`) will likely cause the data to be materialised into memory.

Comment: Why don't you do `r => r.amount` instead of `r => r.field<decimal>("Amount")`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: it's not a database but a [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) which is an in-memory collection

Comment: @DavidG I wasn't perhaps explicit enough, one you put `AsEnumerable` you are no longer working with `iQueryable` and so any LINQ operators that are called will use the `IEnumerable` version and so will not be translated to SQL

Comment: @TimSchmelter that was not mentioned explicitly in the question but you are right now that I look at the code, my bad.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: sure, it's mentioned in the first sentence :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case [`Convert.ToDecimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6440ed8(v=vs.110).aspx) is perfect which works with all numeric types([`IConvertible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
 var query = from row in data.AsEnumerable()
             group row by row.Field<string>("ID") into grp
             select new
             {
                 Id = grp.Key,
                 sum = grp.Sum(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r["AMOUNT"])
             };
```